# Django project with Javascript function doing nothing

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to create some Javascript functions to manipulate an HTML page within a Django project, but literally nothing is happening when I create my functions and I can't understand why.

I have the feeling it's something extremely basic that I'm missing - I'm brand new to working with Javascript within a Django project.

The code below mostly provided by the instructor for a course I'm in and it all works just fine. But when I try to add to the javascript file, I can't get it to do anything.

Specifically I'm just trying to create a button that will run a function (compose_email). The function in question has been created for me by the course instructor, and works just fine when the "compose" button is clicked.

When I try creating a "test" button to call the compose_email function, literally nothing happens when I click the button.

Any tips on what I'm missing here? Again, I feel like it's probably something simple I'm overlooking.

Here is the button I added to the HTML file:

```
'<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="test">TEST</button>'
```

Here is the full HTML file:
'''
{% extends "mail/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

```
{% block body %}
    <h2>{{ request.user.email }}</h2>

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="test">TEST</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
'''
```

And this is the javascript line I added - trying to make it so when the user clicks the "test" button, the compose_email function runs:

```
'document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', compose_email);'
```

Again, literally nothing happens when I click it. Here is the full .js file, with my one line added. Everything else in this file works as expected except for my one line:

```
'''
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);

  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');

});

function compose_email() {

  // Show compose view and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

  // Clear out composition fields
  document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
  document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';


  };


function load_mailbox(mailbox) {
  
  // Show the mailbox and hide other views
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'none';

  // Show the mailbox name
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').innerHTML = `<h3>${mailbox.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + mailbox.slice(1)}</h3>`;

  };
'''
```

Any help is appreciated! I've been banging my head against the wall on this all day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why django doing this but when you add js file and then you change it then that change not apply for code you need to clear browser memory

My suggestion is create js file with html extensions and include that in your file while development

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what the issue was. I actually found another post for doing a hard refresh by pressing Ctrl+F5 (I'm using Chrome) to reload the page when you make changes to the .js file and that worked perfectly!